# HTML-Fileupload using Firefox Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox

I'm a webdeveloper from Germany and I've got a problem with Firefox Android (different versions, current version I use is 23.0).

I developed a web application which has become very huge and complex.

It works fine but there's one PHP site which produces one or more bugs.

This site contains four HTML standard file controls. Here's the HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="input_fileupload_01" name="input_fileupload_01"  accept="image/*; capture=camera">               

<input type="file" id="input_fileupload_02" name="input_fileupload_02" accept="image/*; capture=camera">            

<input type="file" id="input_fileupload_03" name="input_fileupload_03" accept="image/*; capture=camera">

<input type="file" id="input_fileupload_04" name="input_fileupload_04" accept="image/*; capture=camera">
```

When I click one control Firefox opens the dialog for selecting a device.
That's OK.

When I select the smart phone camera (and that's one of the most important features of my application) and shot a photo then sometimes there happen very extremely things:

- FF closes itself with a fatal system error.
- FF closes my web application's browser tab and opens a new browser tab starting my application's index site.

What's wrong? Please watch my HTML code - is there something wrong?
It is so simple. Why do those errors happen?

I hope you've seen that I cut all the upload logic - I did that for testing.

What's the reason FF "kills itself" after I shot a photo or selected an existing photo file from one of the local devices?

What is the error source: HTML, Firefox, the smart phone camera or something else? Please help me.

Thomas